# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase' - even though i installed firebase

Tags: python, database, firebase

I want to connect my database from firebase to my python code so i can get a graph connected to my website and the python error i get keeps saying I don't have the import 'firebase', I've tried downloading it to my packages and plug-ins and changing the variation to make it work but may be its just because I have a Mac. Code down below.

```
from firebase import firebase

myDBConn = firebase.FirebaseApplication("https://sendyearproject-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/",None)#connects to db

file = open("info2.csv", "r")
rawData = file.read()
finalData = rawData.split(",")[1:]# get rid of the first element in the csv file
print(finalData)# prints the csv file


for item in finalData:
    data = { #creates the data to send
       'temp' : item
     }
    myDBConn.post('ireTemps',data)
        #sending data to the db
```

This is the error:
from firebase import firebase
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase'

Comment: Which command you have used and mention python version please

Comment: I used Python 3.6

Comment: And command to install firebase module??

Comment: I installed it on packages and plug-ins, im sorry not sure what you mean by command. I use the firebase website. to create the database and get the link I mean

Comment: command means have install package via `pip install package-name` like that in your case it should be `pip install python-firebase` and it supports till python 3.2 and further details you can find in [docs](https://pypi.org/project/python-firebase/) and your python version in 3.6 you have to create separate environment

Comment: Thanks, I put this at the start of my code ```pip install requests == 1.1.0
pip install python-firebase``` and it still didn't work. I got this error: pip install requests == 1.1.0
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Go through how to install packages in Mac you don't have to include in your code

Comment: I am using Thonny to code and i installed Firebase into the packages but i get this error:  import python_jwt as jwt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_jwt'

Comment: Try to solve errors by finding topics on stack overflow and envauttauly you will get to learn so install whatever requires and after that error still persist you can edit your post with full traceback !

Comment: Alright, Thank you!